# make a certain file type hidden

Tags: macos

I am trying to find a way to make my mac see .dSYM files as hidden. I know I could do:

```
chflags hidden / -name *.dSYM
```

but the next time I create a .dSYM file it wont be hidden. There must be a way to tell finder to hide a certain file type (all currently on my machine, plus all that I will create in the future).

I am assuming that just because it is hidden, it wont affect my ability to use the .dSYM files when I am running cgdb in terminal? Or do the have to be not hidden for cgdb to be able to find them?

(I am on Mountain Lion)

Comment: There isn't a direct way to do this. If the .dSYM files only occur in a few folders, Folder Actions might be an option.

Comment: so you are suggesting to create a folder action that runs the bash code above everytime a file is added to one of my regular folders? do folder actions apply to subfolders of the folder that the action was applied to?

Comment: AFAIK folder actions are only triggered in the respective folders

Comment: So would it affect the operation of cgdb if the .dSYM files are hidden or should it still function OK?

Comment: cgdb isn't impacted, `chflags` only works on Finder level (Finder itself and any Open/Save dialogs)

Comment: I cant get the chflags to work recursively. I am doing this from the directory where I want all of its subfolders to be affected. I am going:
chflags -R hidden *.dSYM
but it says:
*.dSYM isnt a directory.

How can I make this command work recursively for all .dSYM files?

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.dSYM' -exec chflags hidden '{}' +`

Comment: That worked well

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a direct way to do this. There are several alternatives though:

- Folder Actions: Create a folder action (which gets triggered upon each change in a folder) to run the `chflags` command if needed. As Folder Actions only apply to to one folder this needs an Action for every folder you create .dSYM files in
- launchd: Use `WatchPaths` to run a script whenever one of the listed paths is modified
- [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php): Hazel is kind of like Folder Actions on steroids and allows you to create actions based on various rules

PS: cgdb isn't affected, `chflags` only makes files invisible on Finder level (and in Open/Save dialogs).

Comment: i like the idea of using launchd with watchpaths. Is this very resource consuming? Or does it actually do nothing until it is triggered? Also, is there a way to make the watchpaths command recursive?

Comment: It does "nothing" til triggered. The watchpath statement isn't recursive but you can list as many directories as you want. And you can use `find` the create the directory list in the first place.

Comment: I am a student and have to make new directories a couple of times every week for each new task. So i need a way of automating this for subdirectories. Is it possible to set a folder action on a directory that has the task of setting a folder action on each new directory placed in it?