# Hide all files of the same extension in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, file-extensions

I need to hide all files with .pek extension on Finder (macOS Sierra) automatically.

Comment: Do you want it as a one shot solution? Or every time when the new file with `.pek` extension is created?

Comment: I need it every time when the new file with .pek extension is created.
Thanks!

Comment: So you need to check this thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63470/make-a-certain-file-type-hidden
TL;DR: there's no direct way of doing this, you have to create a service for that.

Comment: I try understand it, but I think my knowledge is a little poor. Right now, I'm a little lost. I don't know how create a WatchPaths to run a script about my question. I need help! :(

Ah! Also I seen different options with Automator, but I think that it's not possible.
Thanks!

Comment: You can easily change the filenames to .filenames.  then you can set show hidden files to off.  The . (dot) in front of file names will prevent these files from being shown with show hidden files set to off.  I don't know how to automate this but I'm sure its doable.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've changed the Peter Hosey's [fs-notifier](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/fs-notifier/downloads/), so that it will set the newly created `.pak` files hidden. You will need Xcode for the compilation.

Please change those lines in his code:

In **Notifier.m** change 25th line to:

```
 stream = FSEventStreamCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, newCallback, &context, (CFArrayRef)paths, kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, /*latency*/ 1.0, kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents);`
```

In **fs-notifier.m** file change the whole body of the `gotEvent` fuction (lines 34+) to:

```
NSArray *eventPaths = eventPathsVoidPointer;
if (*eventFlags | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents) {
    NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[@"file://" stringByAppendingString:[eventPaths objectAtIndex:0UL]]];
    if ([fileUrl.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"pak"]) {
        [fileUrl setResourceValue:@YES forKey:NSURLIsHiddenKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

Note: In order to compile the sources you might need to set the 64bit architecture.

After the compilaton you'll launch the program with the path to the directory you want to monitor.

I've tested it and it works, however I don't know what's the impact on the system.

Edit: To hide `.pak` files already created, run this command:

```
find -x /path/to/folder -name \*.pak -exec chflags hidden {} +
```

Answer from [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/60298).